# Replaced MB, CPU and RAM but my PC still won't turn on, GPU just blinks

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure, gpu

So I had an issue that at some point where I unplugged all peripherals from my PC as I was preparing to move. Then after I plugged everything back, it wouldn't turn on and LED 1 green light on my GPU would blink. I brought it to service and they told me to replace MB. I bought new MB, CPU and RAM, installed everything but still get the same result. PSU paper clip test proves that it works. How do I troubleshoot this???

MB: X470 Aorus

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600

RAM: G.Skill Ripjaws DDR4 8GBx2

GPU: GTX 760 from Asus

Power: EVGA SuperNOVA NEX750B 80PLUS

Answer (score 0):

Take everything out but the CPU, and try to start it, Keep adding stuff until it doesn't start. if it doesn't stay on with only the CPU, Your Power Supply is Probably the problem, If you have another PSU lying around, Try using that one to test it, before buying one.

Comment: Taking ou everything else but CPU didn't help, nothing powers up. I'll borrow friend's PSU to test if it works.